# Usage of @Scheduled in spring

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a component class

```
@Component
public class Scheduler
{
     @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000 )
     public void test()
     {
        System.out.println("Hi");
     }
}
```

But "Hi" is not being printed every 5 seconds. Why?

My Confuration class is

```
@ComponentScan( excludeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter( type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE ) } )
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application 
{
    public static void main( final String[] args )
    {
        LOG.debug("Booting Spring Application ...... ");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled Scheduling using `@EnableScheduling`?

Comment: Ya I did in Application.java. Do I have to use any @Bean annotation??

Comment: Is your Scheduler class a bean?

Comment: Ya. It is annotated with @Component

Comment: Can you show us the code of the Application.java class as well?

Comment: It is added in the edit

Comment: what iy your directory structure. I mean where is your main class and Scheduler class relatively

Answer (score 0):

In your main application class add  `@EnableScheduling`  and also see that package in which Scheduler is kept is scanned by using  `@ComponentScan` if all packages are not scanned by you.

```
@EnableScheduling 
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration 
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "springboot.service,springboot.dao,springboot.rest,springboot.schedule,springboot.controller")
public class StartUpController {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(StartUpController.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your Scheduler class in the same or a sub-package of your application class? If not, you have to add the `base-packages` attribute to the `@ComponentScan` annotation, so that the Scheduler component will be found.

Comment: My application class is in the package `com.abc` and the scheduler class is in the packge `com.abc.xyz`